# Calling Event Handler and using DBContext inside throws "disposed context" exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I have a Service that handles a file upload. After the upload is finished, I'm raising the upload complete event. Inside the event, I want to set the "upload finished" state and write the "upload finished date". I'm facing a "disposed context" exception when the event handler is fetching my entity from the DB.

"Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances."

My DBContext is instantiated via dependency injection in the service constructor and the DBContext is set to scoped lifetime in the service installer. The lifetime of the service itself is set to transient.

Here is my code. (I deleted the unnecessary stuff):

```
        public FileService(
            SpotUploadDbContext dbContext,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                             IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
            IOptions<FolderSettings> folderSettings,
            IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> stringLocalizer,
            IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            this._dbContext = dbContext;
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            this._appSettings = appSettings.Value;
            this._folderSettings = folderSettings.Value;
            this._defaultFormOptions = new FormOptions
            {
                MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue
            };
            this._stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
            this.hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;

            // Bind event here
            this.UploadCompleted += this.FileService_UploadCompleted;
        }


        public async Task UploadFileAsync(Guid spotId)
        {
         // ...
var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
                var boundary = RequestHelpers.GetBoundary(
                    MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType),
                    this._defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
                var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);
                var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                var fileId = spotId.ToString();
                UploadCompletedEventArgs eventArgs = null;
                var extension = string.Empty;
                var trustedFileName = string.Empty;
                var fileName = "testfile.mp3";

                while (section is not null)
                {
                    var hasContentDispositionHeader =
                        ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition);
                    if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
                    {
                        // ...
                        if (RequestHelpers.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                        {
                            trustedFileName = fileId + extension;

                            var targetStream = this.CreateFileStreamFromUploadAsync(fileId, extension);

                            eventArgs ??= new UploadCompletedEventArgs
                            {
                                FileId = fileId,
                                OriginalFileName = fileName,
                                TrustedFileName = trustedFileName,
                                FileSize = contentDisposition.Size,
                                FilePath = targetStream.Name,
                                SpotId = spotEntity.Id
                            };

                            await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
                        }
                        else if (RequestHelpers.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                        {
                            var key = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name);
                            var encoding = GetEncoding(section);

                            using var streamReader = new StreamReader(section.Body, encoding, true, 1024, true);
                            var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                            formAccumulator.Append(key.Value, value);

                            // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Drain any remaining section body that hasn't been consumed and
                    // read the headers for the next section.
                    section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                }

                // Multipartreader should be finished here (while loops stopped)
                // Raise upload completed event
                this.UploadCompleted?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
                
                // ...
                await this._dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
           }


        private async void FileService_UploadCompleted(object sender, UploadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uploadState = await this._dbContext.LovSpotUploadState.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
            x.Id == SpotUploadStates.UploadFinished);

            // Exception is thrown here!
            var spot = await this._dbContext.Spots.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == e.SpotId);

            spot.UploadEndDate = DateTime.Now;
            spot.SpotUploadState = uploadState;

            await this._dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

As the DBContext lifetime is scoped I was assuming, that the event handler would work and the entity should be updated correctly.